# Updating Istio-IngressGateway TLS Cert

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, istio

I have a scenario where I need to update the Ingress gateway tls cert `(/etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt)` and key every 24 hours. I am able to fetch the raw bytes and create the secret using C# Kubernetes client, **but unless the Ingress Gateway restarts, it does not pick up the updated certs.** Is there a way to do that through code without restarting the ingress-gateway deployment?

Any other suggestions is also highly appreciated.

Comment: How is the certificate bound to the gateway. Can you please provide your configuration code

Comment: Secret has been created using : `kubectl create -n istio-system secret tls istio-ingressgateway-certs --key tls.key --cert tls.crt` and gateway (partial) looks like : `selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: https
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_2
      maxProtocolVersion: TLSV1_3
    hosts:
    - "*"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mounting your cert/key by file reference. Istio supports `SDS` now, so you can mount the cert by `credentialName` . This mode will detect a new cert without restarting. From docs:

```
 apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mygateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: httpbin-credential # must be the same as secret
    hosts:
    - httpbin.example.com
```

Btw: docs state that...

> The secret name should **not begin with istio** or prometheus, and the secret should not contain a token field.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/#configure-a-tls-ingress-gateway-for-a-single-host